# react-native f8 components

Tags: facebook, react-native

ListContainer,ScheduleListView in facebook f8 is the exactly components that I want. But it is too difficult to override these components by myself. Is there any other components having similar characteristics. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

ListContainer was added to my project and it worked well except the parallaxBackground. Because it lies behind the listView so it can not detect touch events...trying to override it ...